# Acumatica REST API New ID based on numbering sequence

Tags: acumatica, myob

I have a custom webservice endpoint based on the Customer object and can successfully POST (actually PUT in Acumatica) new records. However, I am required to pass a CustomerId with the request.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so that the CustomerId is assigned based on the numbering sequence configuration please?

Comment: If you have solve your issue please post your solution and accept so others that may encounter the same problem can benefit of your experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had a configuration issue on the Segmented Keys ScreenId=CS202000. The Customers Segmented Key was not flagged to Auto Number